# Scientific notation in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a source table with a column that stored as LEDGER_BAL_AMT as a String value, I have loaded this LEDGER_BAL_AMT as FLOAT in target table by using BIGQUERY.

When I query for this column I get it as a scientific notation like this:

6.2998225E7

But i need the output should be stored as FLOAT and the value like below

62998225.0

Answer (score 1):

Try [FORMAT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string): `select FORMAT('%.1f', 6.2998225E7)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this one, but this one storing as sting type in target table. I want target table column datatype as float only not string.